# GetSaveFileName / IFileSaveDialog - event on user input / react to file name change?

Tags: c++, c, winapi

I'm currently using a [GetSaveFileName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/ms646928.aspx) dialog in my C++ application. *(As I know this was superseded by the [IFileDialog interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/bb775966.aspx) I choose not to limit this question to the deprecated API but to accept solutions for both implementations).*

The challenge is to react to user input (i.e. the user typing manually into the filename input) and modify the file dialog accordingly.

As a specific example consider automatically changing the file type in the file type dropdown when the user manually enters a supported file extension.

---

I had hoped that the `lpfnHook` member of the [OPENFILENAME](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/ms646839.aspx) structure could do that for me, unfortunately it seems there is no event triggered for typed characters in the filename input.

Comment: This kind of behavior is already supported out of box (at least with  IFileDialog). User can type file filter in file name edit box and apply it by pressing Enter.

Comment: I can't see that: pressing enter in the file name edit box is equivalent to pressing "Save" - it does not change the file filter. Please note that the application has multiple output options with the same extension, i.e. the user has to choose while the dialog is still open and an unambiguous selection based on file extension is not possible after the user closed the dialog.

Comment: By file filter I mean something like `*.png`. Presence of `*` makes it work as a filter instead of ending file selection dialog when Enter is pressed. It should work.

Comment: Ah, I see the confusion: I don't want to set the file filter only to filter the files in the dialog - I need the file filter to set the output format (we can safely assume it's a file save dialog). The intention is that the user can enter `image.png` and the file filter (and therefore the output format) is automatically set to "Portable Network Graphics (*.png)".

Comment: Don't think that's going to be possible. Why don't you just stick to the platform standards and avoid confusing your poor users?

Comment: 1) My "confused" users ask for it. 2) The platform "standard" might be even more confusing (or do you think it's intuitive behavior if a user types `image.png` and finds the file saved as e.g. `image.png.jpg`?)

Comment: I never noticed such a behaviour. Launch notepad.exe, press Ctrl+S, enter "image.png". The file will be saved as such, despite I had "text files" choosen in the file types drop down box.

Comment: Depends on the application. For example Microsoft Office programs always append a valid file extension based on the file type chosen. The behavior you describe would be highly undesirable (even worse than the behavior I described) as it results in an invalid file extension (i.e. mismatch between actual type and extension) and is probably the worst choice an application designer can make.

Comment: I don't agree. For some applications it is valid to accept *any* file extension. For instance, I might want to save a *.ini file using Notepad. Of course Notepad can't know every possible file extension that designates a text file. In your case, I would handle [`IFileDialogEvents::OnFileOK()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775879(v=vs.85).aspx) where you can check if the user has entered an invalid extension and return `S_FALSE` to reject it. Would that be an acceptable answer?

Comment: You're right that for some applications (notably texteditors) saving with arbitrary extension can be acceptable, but for any program saving binary formats and most programs saving text files with predefined format it's not useful. As explained above I can not determine the file extension after the user clicked OK as there are multiple formats producing the same format. It has to happen while the dialog is open, either manually by the user (status-quo) or automatically based on extension (which I want to implement) but leaving the user with the possibility to adjust the automatic choice.

Comment: I believe I begin to understand. ;-) I think the easiest thing you could do is to [add control(s) to the dialog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776913(v=vs.85).aspx#customizing) to let the user choose the format depending on file extension. If you want to react immediately when the user is typing, you could subclass the edit control or use UI automation, but that is likely to break with future Windows versions.

Answer (score 1):

The correct solution is to create the saved file using whatever filename the user types in, and format the file's content based on the selected filter. The user should be free to change the filter as desired before closing the dialog.

There is no need to react to individual key presses. But, if you must, then when using the legacy `GetSaveFileName()` API, the only option is to subclass the filename Edit field directly, such as with `SetWindowSubclass()`. You can get the Edit field's `HWND` using `GetDlgItem()` with the `edt1` or `cmb13` control ID. The subclass can intercept key press messages, then send the dialog a `CDM_GETFILEPATH` message to get the currently typed filename, parse the extension from it, and manually update the filter combo box accordingly. You can get the combo box's `HWND` using `GetDlgItem()` with the `cmb1` control ID.

However, on Vista and later, `GetSaveFileName()` is just a wrapper for the newer `IFileSaveDialog` API when ComCtl32 v6 is used, so the above is not guaranteed to work anymore. But you can try it.

If you use the newer `IFileDialog` API directly, it does allow you to customize the dialog with new controls via `IFileDialogCustomize`, but it does not allow you to subclass existing controls (it provides no access to the `HWND`s of the dialog or its controls. You would have to resort to lower level hooks to access them). If you did manage to subclass the filename Edit field, you could use `IFileDialog::GetFileName()` to retrieve the currently typed filename, but you can't update the filter combo box directly, as `IFileDialog::SetFilterTypeIndex()` can't be called once the dialog is displayed (unless you can figure out a way to get its `HWND`). On Vista only, you could try not specifying a filter at all (or, at least, a filter of `*.*`), and then use a combination of `IFileDialogCustomize::AddComboBox()` and `IFileDialogControlEvents::OnItemSelected` to simulate a manual filter list, and `IFileDialog::SetFilter()` to specify which items appear in the dialog based on the selected filter. But, `SetFilter()` is deprecated and no longer works in Windows 7 and later.